# How to get past lazy loading selenium web scraping

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I'd like to grab more than the first 10 entries from the following site, but it looks like it only loads once you scroll down on the web page.. Any ideas on how to get more than the first 10?

Site [here](https://seatgeek.com/dodgers-at-cubs-tickets/5-5-2021-chicago-illinois-wrigley-field/mlb/5316885).

Sample code:

```
driver.get(g)
price = [i.text for i in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-test='event-listing']//a/span")))]
price = [x.replace('\n', '') for x in price] #added to get rid of newline character in each list element
price = [x.replace('/ea', '') for x in price] #added to get rid of newline character in each list element
loc = [i.text for i in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-test='event-listing']//div[@data-test='section']")))]
detail = [i.text for i in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-test='event-listing']//span[@data-test='quantity']")))]
```

Comment: what was wrong with using the api as I offered in your previous question? That gets you all the entries for the game.

Comment: I posted this question before getting your response. That API works perfectly, thank you.

Comment: Excellent. Be sure to go back and accept that solution then.